# Jmeter - Variation in count of different http requests within same thread group

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Requirement: Load for a total of 100 users within an hour. Each user hits 3 different services different number of times at the same time.

for example: user 1 is going to hit service1- 3 times, service2- 5 times and service3 - 4 times at the same time. Same will be repeated for 100 users over 1 hour.

I have a thread with users-100, rampup time -60 (min). and then I am using parallel plugin and within that plugin created those 3 different sample requests. But I don't know how to configure the number of times, each of those service will be called per user at the same time.

Comment: What kind of parallel plugin do you use?

Comment: parallel plugin is provided by blazemeter.
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Your test scenario doesn't make sense, normally 1 thread (virtual user) can hit only one endpoint at a time. The use when user executes 3 same requests to the same endpoint looks very suspicious as well. So I would recommend reconsidering your scenario and implement distribution using one of the following approaches:

1. Use different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for different requests
2. Use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
3. Use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
4. Use [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide)

---

If however I'm wrong and you're trying to implement some form of [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) testing when requests are being triggered at the same time and in parallel - example test plan would be something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! For now, I have the exact same setup what you specified but I wasn't convinced with this approach. Because I won't be able to paramterize it. for example if tomorrow, any request gets executed one additional time, I would have to manually add it to the jmx script. That's why I was wondering if there is an efficient way of doing it. I do appreciate you looking into my problem and providing your valuable inputs.